# Getting a program to start over and get a new value?

Tags: c++

I am working with a program which requires a value to put in a variable and do some stuff on it.  The problem is that I want the program to start over again and ask the user for a new value to process the new value again.

For example look at this code, which requires a number as a grade to rate it.  When the processing was done I want the program to ask for a new grade ( next student for instance ).

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    cout<< " Please Enter your grade : " ;
    cin>>n;
    switch (n/10) {
        case 10: cout<< " A+ : Great! ";

        case 9:
            break;
        case 8: cout<< " A : Very Good ";
            break;

        case 7: cout<< " B : Good " ;
            break;
        case 6: 
        case 5:
        case 4:
        case 3:
        case 2:
        case 1:
        case 0: cout<< " Failed ";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple "while(x)" solve your problem?

Comment: Why would someone vote the question down? Seems quite an unfriendly thing to do...

Comment: unrelated to your question, but I believe you would want to allow fall through for the case of 9, otherwise 9 will be treated as nothing, no A+, no A, just no result

Comment: @Evgeni B. Because people forget that they were once rookies too. But we all have to start somewhere. Good luck Ali, it's a long road ahead, but it's a fun ride.

Comment: @pstrjds Thanks pal, no it's just for a test! Not a big deal

Comment: @RenanGreinert Yeah man that does well :) Thanks

Comment: @Philip Thanks man, That was quite inspirational. You rock man, Yeah it's abso-bloody-lutely fun :) Long long road ahead, indeed :D Good Luck too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [while loop](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html)

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    while(1) {
        cout<< " Please Enter your grade : " ;
        cin>>n;
        switch (n/10) {
            case 10: cout<< " A+ : Great! ";

            case 9:
            case 8: cout<< " A : Very Good ";
                break;

            case 7: cout<< " B : Good " ;
                break;
            case 6: 
            case 5:
            case 4:
            case 3:
            case 2:
            case 1:
            case 0: cout<< " Failed ";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        cout<<"do you wish to continue?(y/n)";
        cin>>some_declared_variable;
        if (some_declared_variable == 'n')
            break; //hopefully this will break the infinite loop
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem statement says it does not want to.

Comment: Personally, I'd use a do/while loop instead of a standard while to guarantee it executes at least once.  Also, an optional stop value wouldn't hurt so you don't have to Ctrl+C to terminate.

Comment: the `while(1)`would loop forever, untill you kill the process. you could use some kind of "poison pill", for example `while(n != -1)`so if the user types -1, the programm exits gracefully. of course, you need to read in `n`first. do a separate statement for that or use the do-while loop

Comment: A programmer learns while earlier than a Do...while, so usage of while here will help the questioner more than other relatively complex constructs.

Comment: @EvgeniB. Thanks man, That's so sweet. For both your sympathy and helping me with your fascinating solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, It's quite awesome :) Donnu how to thank you. Trying your methods now.